# How can I take backup before doing releasing new changes in vsts

Tags: azure-devops, task, devops

I have a release definition,now I want to take the backup of old one before deploying new one if any know the answer please share the steps or picture
Because I'm new to CI/cd

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, seems you want Azure DevOps for a release definition to have a step that backs up the directory for the application before it deploys the updated code.

There are a [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and a [Archive Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) task which you can drop into your process. You can even make the tasks conditional based on your needs.

When you want the "old" release, the normal thing to do would be to schedule a new release with the previous version to install. Or to fix the issue and trigger a new release with the fixed contents.